# Geoserver tutorial disabled by Google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geoserver

I try to make the tutorial work that geoserver has in its documentation:

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/georss/georss.html

Since Google maps v2 is deprecated and its keys with it I obtained a v3 API-key via the Google web console and put it in that like this:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=3.x&amp;key=[my key for v3 here]" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It shows the map as expected but after a few seconds I get:

> Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application.

and the map is gone.

Could it be, that this tutorial is just severely outdated? So do I need to find a tutorial on using geoserver with Google Maps v3 ?

Comment: This tutorial is based on Maps-API V2, of course it's outdated when V2 is deprecated(and it will not work with V3). Furthermore you're not loading the V3-API, the `v=3`-parameter did not load Version3, because the path for v3 is completely different.

Comment: Thanks for the clearification. I guess I was a bit naive. So in short: this tutorial though still on the geoserver-site is useless and I will have to find a newer one.

Answer (score 0):

The way to display RSS layers in the Google Maps API v3 is to use [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers)

Example from the referenced documentation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>GeoRSS Layers</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.496675,-102.65625);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/geo/?g=322338@N20&lang=en-us&format=feed-georss'
  });
  georssLayer.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```